# Android RSS reader that removes duplicate articles

Tags: android, feed-reader

I use Feedly to read articles from a variety of sources on a daily basis. The only problem I have with Feedly is that when a big news story hits I have half-a-dozen or so articles all on the same thing which really messes with my feed.

I would like to find an RSS reader that will automatically hide articles with similar titles/subjects. Does anyone know of anything?

- Add feeds from a variety of sources
- Read articles via the web
- Read articles via Android

I would be willing to pay.

Comment: A solution that works is passing all of the feeds through Yahoo! Pipes.

Comment: not tested, and not sure whether it works stand-alone: but [ownCloud News Reader seems to support that](https://github.com/owncloud/News-Android-App/issues/513).

Answer (score 2):

## [Inoreader](https://www.inoreader.com/)

I use Inoreader. It has a filter to remove ones with matching titles. Unfortunately this filtering does not affect mobile apps. You could also set up advanced filtering rules

[image]

It also has a wide array of features which include:

- Free and paid plans for extended features
- Search feeds from a variety of sources, browse by category, or add via an RSS link
- Has a web reader at [inoreader.com](https://www.inoreader.com/)
- Has an [Android app on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.innologica.inoreader)